# Wordpress Posts odd/even Li layout

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, html-lists

I am working on a custom theme and on one of the pages i need to style the posts pages as follows: http://gyazo.com/e1f7cfc03c7ba3981188077afcdf0314

The grey box is an image and the red box is content. I need to use perhaps an odd/even Li/Ul pseudo class/selector but i have no idea how to do it.

Could anyone offer me a way to start it up? I was thinking of using the Odd/Even pseudo class on UL to change the divs names however i can't think how to do it or where to start.

Thanks!

Edit: I am thinking perhaps odd/even selector combined with jquery prepend/append?

Edit2: this is what i have however it is displaying all the Odds first then all of the Evens instead of alternatively.

PHP:

```
       <?php $i++; if(($i % 2) == 0) : $wp_query->next_post(); else : the_post(); ?>


<div class="section group">

<div class="col span_1_of_2 blue doubleheight">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?></a>

</div>

     <div class="col span_1_of_3_30 blue doubleheight">
     <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
     <div class="post-text"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
     </div>


</div>
<?php echo $i; ?>
 <?php endif; endwhile; ?>



<?php while(have_posts()) : ?>

<?php $i++; if(($i % 2) !== 0) : $wp_query->next_post(); else : the_post(); ?>

<div class="section group">
<div class="col span_1_of_3_30 blue doubleheight">
     <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<div class="post-text"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div></div>



<div class="col span_1_of_2 blue doubleheight">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?></a>
</div>

</div>
<?php echo $i; ?>
<?php endif; endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Yeah i have posted my code in the original post thank you

Comment: If you have a layout you need (the image on the left, and text on the right, for instance), and that is just repeating, you can use `:nth-child(2n)` pseudoselector, and use css to make image float (or absolute position them) on a different side. That way every other element will have that positioning.

Comment: Problem is, i use a Div for the image and a Div for the information so i am not sure this would work ?

Comment: If they are in the wrapper that has the same class every time, then just target that wrapper. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/gq5veb9L/

Comment: This works great, a nice clean way of implementing this thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are in the loop, you can use the build in loop counter (`$wp_query->current-post`) to add a different class to all odds or all evens or both

There is no need to run two loops. Here is an example of how I use this in my website to create two post columns

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  ?>
        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>

        <div class="entry-content-<?php if( $wp_query->current_post%2 == 1 ){ echo ' left-post';}else{ echo ' right-post';} ?>">
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**EDIT**

I misunderstood you in my original answer, but you can still use the same idea as I used there. Here is something you can try. Just replace all your code with this

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  ?>
    <?php /* Start the Loop */ 

        if($wp_query->current_post%2 == 1 ) { ?>

            <div class="section group">

                <div class="col span_1_of_2 blue doubleheight">

                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?></a>

                </div>

                <div class="col span_1_of_3_30 blue doubleheight">
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <div class="post-text">
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>

        <?php }else{ ?>

            <div class="section group">
                <div class="col span_1_of_3_30 blue doubleheight">
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <div class="post-text">
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="col span_1_of_2 blue doubleheight">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?></a>
                </div>

            </div>

        <?php }

    <?php endwhile; ?>

 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This is a much cleaner way of dealing with the loop however i am not sure if i can implement this into my current code. I have just tried for an hour and couldn't get it to work. Basically the image set from a post is in a Div and the content (text/title) is also in a div those 2 divs are in a container row and i adjust the width of each div to give the look of the layout from the screenshot. If you think i can still implement this feel free to tell me, thanks for your time!