# Wordpress odd and even posts

Tags: wordpress, post

I am moving static website to wordpress. What I'm trying to achieve is to display every second post with image on the left and content on the right, like on this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sscdh.jpg.
Is there any simple solution for that? 
The problem is i need to also change HTML, not only .css classes to move the image.
Static website html code:

```
          <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-12">
          <div class="row inspiracje-article-box">
          <div class="inspiracje-article-text col-lg-8">
            <h2>Projekt / aranżacja / homestaging</h2>
            <h3>brzmi podobnie, a czym to tak naprawdę jest.</h3>
            <p>
              Przede wszystkim należy zdać sobie pytanie dla kogo i w jakim
              celu. Odpowiedź na te dwa zasadniczo proste pytania będzie
              kluczem do tego, z jaką usługą mamy…
              <a href="artykul.html" class="czytaj-dalej">Czytaj Dalej</a>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="inspiracje-article-img col-lg-4">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/artykul_1.jpg" alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-12">
          <div class="row inspiracje-article-box article-right">
          <div class="inspiracje-article-img col-lg-4">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/artykul_moodboard.jpg" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="inspiracje-article-text col-lg-8">
            <h2>Moodboard</h2>
            <h3>Podtytuł do artykułu moodboard.</h3>
            <p>
              Moodboard, czyli „tablica” z graficzną prezentacją koncepcji,
              wprowadzająca nas w nastrój i klimat projektowanego wnętrza. …
              <a href="artykul.html" class="czytaj-dalej">Czytaj Dalej</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-12">
          <div class="row inspiracje-article-box">
            <div class="inspiracje-article-text col-lg-8">
              <h2>Home Staging</h2>
              <h3>Jaki jest zakres prac?</h3>
              <p>
                To jest pytanie na które odpowiedź możliwa jest dopiero po
                ocenie stanu faktycznego nieruchomości. Przygotowanie
                nieruchomości do sprzedaży we współpracy z Home Stagerem
                gwarantuje …
                <a href="artykul.html" class="czytaj-dalej">Czytaj Dalej</a>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="inspiracje-article-img col-lg-4">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="img/artykul_3.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

and content.php file from wordpress:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <div class="col-xl-12">
          <div class="row inspiracje-article-box">
          <div class="inspiracje-article-text col-lg-8">
    <?php
    if ( is_singular() ) :
        the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' );
    else :
        the_title( '<h2><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' );
    endif;
    ?>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="inspiracje-article-img col-lg-4">
            <?php
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image( $post_thumbnail_id, 'full', '', ["class" => "img-fluid"] );
            }
            ?>
            <?php echo $image_url; ?>
          </div>
          <?php
    if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) :
        ?>
        <div><?php edit_post_link('edytuj'); ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
          </div>
          </div>
```

-->

Comment: there are many related posts about this, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25545806/wordpress-posts-odd-even-li-layout)

Comment: Thank you, solution from this thread works perfectly!